# Chamar módulo dentro de outro módulo no VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

To tendo uns problemas para importar um módulo dentro de outro no meu código VBA. Basicamente, tenho uma planilha de ordem de serviço onde eu tenho um botão macro na faixa de opções que eu personalizei no excel para criar uma cópia (duplicar) a planilha que uso como base para criar as outras. Logo, possuo varias planilhas de ordem de serviço para cada cliente.

Nesse macro de duplicar, eu to tentando adicionar outro módulo após duplicar ele, para limpar o conteúdo da ordem de serviço base (chamada "OS"). Então, por exemplo, tenho a planilha OS que é a minha planilha base, coloco nela os serviços e informações que vou prestar pro cliente FULANO, clico no botão macro de duplicar, ele cria uma cópia da planilha e nomeia automaticamente com o nome do cliente (que fica na célula B10) e o carro dele (B15). Em seguida, eu queria que limpasse o conteúdo da OS base automaticamente (até então, eu estava fazendo manualmente, criava a cópia e depois ia lá limpar a OS base). Porém, no código que fiz, ele parou de criar a cópia, e só está limpando o conteúdo da planilha OS.

Esse é meu código atual:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewClientOS()
    'criar ordem de serviço do cliente
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sCar As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("OS")
    
        sName = ws.[B10].Value
        sCar = ws.[B15].Value
        sTemp = sName & " " & sCar
        Sheets("OS").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sTemp
        
    clearContent

End Sub
 
Sub clearContent()
    'limpar conteúdo da planilha
     
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS")

    ws.Range("rClient").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ws.Range("rWorks").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ws.Range("rObs").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ws.Range("rDescount").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
 
    ws.Range("B10:G10").Select
    
End Sub
```

Se alguém puder e souber me ajudar a resolver esse problema, ficarei muito agradecida.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Quando eu separei em módulos diferentes, esse problema não ocorreu.

No caso, o que eu fiz foi clicar com o botão direito sobre Planilha1(OS)>Inserir>Módulo (imagem abaixo) e, nesse módulo criado, eu inseri o módulo "Clear Contents" e funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, se for o caso de apagar o conteúdo da aba "OS", ao invés de criar módulos separados, eu deixaria o código para apagar o conteúdo na mesma Sub (eu, ao menos, prefiro fazer assim).

Qualquer problema, me avise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub NewClientOS()
'criar ordem de serviço do cliente
Dim sName As String
Dim sCar As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("OS")

    sName = ws.Range("B10").Value
    sCar = ws.Range("B15").Value
    sTemp = sName & " " & sCar
    Sheets("OS").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = sTemp
    
    Call clearContent

 End Sub

 Sub clearContent()
'limpar conteúdo da planilha
 
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS")
ws.Select
ws.Range("rClient").ClearContents
ws.Range("rWorks").ClearContents
ws.Range("rObs").ClearContents
ws.Range("rDescount").ClearContents
ws.Range("B10:G10").Select

End Sub
```